# Optimized implementations of some functions from ctype.h

Tags: c, optimization, func

In one of my C application I am using, below functions from ctype.h :

isalpha(), isspace(), ispunct(), tolower().

After profiling I see there are some bottlenecks in the calls of these functions(Basically my app is a character/string processing from a input text file and hence these functions are called exhaustively inside critical loops)I want to optimize them for speed and have my own implementation if it helps.

Where can I find such or logic to implement them?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with these functions and not with your code caling these functions more often than needed?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I'm not aware of any that do not implement them as table lookup macros and callable functions as alternative. Check in `ctype.h` (you did include it, didn't you?) if there are `#ifdef` that prevent the use of the macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me odd that such functions can be your bottleneck; likely they can take into account the locale, and this makes them "slower". If you can disregard it, then you can implement them as easily as (e.g.: this is just an idea wrote on the fly)

```
bool isalpha(int c)
{
   return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}

bool isspace(int c)
{
   return c == ' ' || c == '\t'; // || whatever other char you consider space
}

bool ispunct(int c)
{
   static const char *punct = ".;!?...";
   return strchr(punct, c) == NULL ? false : true; // you can make this shorter
}

int tolower(int c)
{
   if ( !isalpha(c) ) return c;
   return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c - 'A' : c;
}
```

Then make them inline functions.

Comment: Your `isalpha` and `tolower` assume the char set is ASCII. They'll probably fail in EBCDIC. (Yes, surprisingly there are EBCDIC still around.)

Comment: @ShinTakezou @lhf - Probably its safe for me to assume that my app. would run in a environ of known locale and char set. thanks. Where can I see the existing source code for these functions in GCC 4.4.3 version of compiler I am using. Which folder on the system would have it?

Comment: both works for EBCDIC too, since in EBCDIC too A < B < C < D, as far as I can remember. Anyway, rarely in such situations EBCDIC is a concern.

Comment: @goldenmean you can browse online repos, like e.g. http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=ctype;h=c210b436c171f756a4217c7611f1152e8415c242;hb=db290cf59207aff09d1794e666e2854a93775f32 (you have to search for the GNU C lib, not the compiler source)

Comment: Sure, in EBCDIC A < B < C < D etc, but there are gaps between letters so other chars would be classified as alpha.

Comment: @lhf ok if the OP needs EBCDIC supports he must split treatment for A-I, J-R and S-Z and similar someway; moreover, likely his code will be broken in other part we can't see (e.g. if he dares to write `c == 10` instead of `c == '\n'` ...); btw I am happy that *dynos* tend to disappear or to adapt

Answer (score 4):

You could implement them as macros or inline functions:

```
#define IS_ALPHA(x) (((x) >= 'a' && (x) <= 'z') || ((x) >= 'A' && (x) <= 'Z'))
#define IS_SPACE(x) ((x) == ' ' || (x) == '\t')
... etc.
```

Note however that the original `isalpha`, `isspace`, `ispunct`, etc. depend on the current locale and may yield different results depending on the language.

Answer (score 2):

You can make fast implementations of these functions by using a lookup table of 256 elements. For isalpha(), the i'th element is 1 if the character whose ASCII value is i is an alphanumeric.  Then isalpha is just a table lookup.

You can save some space and encode all of these functions with one table by devoting one bit of each entry to the result of one function. Then each function simply looks up the entry for the character passed in, and masks out the bit that it needs.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

In general the people that write library code are very good software engineers and those functions have been tuned to the nth degree. Unless you can remove some of the cases that those functions have to account for you will have trouble matching their performance.

Comment: Where can i see the source code of library functions. Especially in this case the C library functions from ctype.h I mentioned?

Comment: if you are using gcc there easily available in the library source code.  If you are using a different compiler they may or may not be available

Comment: @goldenmean: That depends on which compiler you are using. Open source compilers usually come with full source code. Some closed-source compilers do this too, or at least with the source code of the runtime. Some compilers only come with the required headers and DLLs. IOW, it depends.

Comment: @rerun - Using GCC -4.3.1. Could you pls. let know what folder/path of the system would have the source for this library?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ctype.h` header - your compiler library probably already provides a way to have these functions inlined or implemented as macros (if inline isn't supported for whatever reason). (By the way - what compiler & target platform are you using?)

If these things are already inlined/macros then you might want to post some details about how you're using the functions.  Maybe there's a way to shortcut calling some of these functions (for example, if `isspace()` is true, you don't need to call `isalpha()` or `ispunct()` since they must not be true).